# Progressively Enhance HTML table with jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, html-table, themes

I can't find an example of jqGrid being used to "paint" an existing clean HTML table. Is this possible? I am currently using datatables http://www.datatables.net/ because it is easy to implement on existing HTML but would prefer jqGrid's theme support and hooks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) - there is an optional module you can download at the bottom called Table to Grid.

Comment: Note that this is included with the regular grid download these days. But you're right that this is how to do it.

Comment: @Craif. Then why the option to select it to download it?

Comment: The customizable download is a new feature in 3.5, I see.